# Sumo and OMNET++

Tags: omnet++

I just edited my map and i can  run it with 100 car using SUMO.. Now i want to launch this map and these cars with omnet++ i created launch file .. and going to ini file and set the launch file

```
Config DSRUU-City]
description = "DSRUU"
*.numHosts = 100
*.manager.launchConfig = xmldoc("..\\_maps\\Mapsprojec\\City.launchd.xml")
*.**.nic.phy80211p.decider = xmldoc("..\\_maps\\Mapsprojec\\config.xml")
*.**.nic.phy80211p.analogueModels = xmldoc("..\\_maps\\Mapsprojec\\config.xml")
*.playgroundSizeX =3000
*.playgroundSizeY =3000
*.playgroundSizeZ = 50m
**.roiRects = "0,100-2200,2000"#x,y-X,Y
```

My problem, When i run the simulation, i can't see the cars as node inside the omnet++ although i can see them in the sumo gui in the same time .. So how i can solve this issue ... So i should see the cars as node in the omnet++ and as car in the sumo ? .. Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Did you make sure that ``*.annotations.draw = true`` is set?

Comment: Thanks mate ... My problem solved .. :)

Comment: Now, I have another question .. If i have road with three lane each lane has own speed like ( 80 , 100 , 120 ) ... Then i need to test the performance of any protocol like the AODV when the vehicle speed is 90m/s .. and the number of vehicle is 100 .. how i can do this i mean set fix speed for these cars .. Thanks in advance ..

Comment: That is a new question, so please write a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to enable the drawing of annotations in your `omnetpp.ini` by adding (or modifying) the line:

```
*.annotations.draw = true
```